# Why I'm getting only one rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
let canvas, ctx, W, H;
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let objArr = [];

const init = () => {
  canvas.width = W = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = H = innerHeight;
  canvas.style.background = '#dedfda';

  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    let r = (i + 1) * 20;
    objArr.push(new Rectangle(W / 2, H / 2, 10, 10, "red", innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, r));
    objArr[0].draw();

  }

  animate();
}

const random = (min = 0, max = 1) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(posX, posY, w, h, color, cx, cy, r) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.cx = cx;
    this.cy = cy;
    this.r = r;
    this.angle = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.w, this.h);
  }
  update() {
    this.angle += 0.1;
    this.posX = this.cx + this.r * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.posY = this.cy + this.r * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.draw();
  }
}



const animate = () => {
  objArr.forEach(e => {
    e.update();
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.onload = init;
```

In this code, I'm expecting an output having 5 rectangles revolving around the center point of the window in different radius like the planets revolving around the Sun in solar system.

But I am getting only one rectangle and it's not even revolving.

Stucked and not getting why it's not working.

Comment: What's the first action in `draw()`? Or in other words: it doesn't make much sense to clear the complete canvas before drawing _one_ rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `draw` function is clearing every time and you are only referencing the first element of the array. Adjusting for both shows 6 objects revolving. Your loop runs from 0 to 5. If you want 5 objects, you'll need to set the upper bound to 4 instead.

```js
let canvas, ctx, W, H;
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let objArr = [];

const init = () => {
  canvas.width = W = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = H = innerHeight;
  canvas.style.background = '#dedfda';

  // adjusted range
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    let r = (i + 1) * 20;
    objArr.push(new Rectangle(W / 2, H / 2, 10, 10, "red", innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, r));
    objArr[i].draw();
  }

  animate();
}

const random = (min = 0, max = 1) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(posX, posY, w, h, color, cx, cy, r) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.cx = cx;
    this.cy = cy;
    this.r = r;
    this.angle = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.w, this.h);
  }
  update() {
    this.angle += 0.1;
    this.posX = this.cx + this.r * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.posY = this.cy + this.r * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.draw();
  }
}

const animate = () => {
  // moved clear here to happen just once on each animate
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  objArr.forEach(e => {
    e.update();
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks... I am having one issue that the code is too heavy, my editor is crashing... Is there any solution to this code.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different issue than the post created here. You might want to create another post asking about this, as I'm assuming the issue has nothing to do with the code we have here but what is going on in the rest of your project. It may also have to do with what program you are using to edit code.

Answer (score 1):

You are just drawing one rectangle. Pay attention to

```js
objArr[0].draw()
```

Which should be

```js
objArr[i].draw()
```

Also, I think everytime an `Rectange` object's `draw` method is called the whole canvas is cleared in this line

```js
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
```

Hence, only one rectangle appears at all times.

A solution would be to move the calls to `clearRect` and `update` from `Rectangle` to the `animate` function. This way it fits better with the program logic. A Rectangle being an object should only know how to draw itself not clearing the canvas and updating its position on the canvas.

Below is my solution.

```js
let canvas, ctx, W, H;
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let objArr = [];

const init = () => {
  canvas.width = W = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = H = innerHeight;
  canvas.style.background = '#dedfda';

  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    let r = (i + 1) * 20;
    objArr.push(new Rectangle(W / 2, H / 2, 10, 10, "red", innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, r));
    objArr[i].draw();

  }

  animate();
}

const random = (min = 0, max = 1) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(posX, posY, w, h, color, cx, cy, r) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.cx = cx;
    this.cy = cy;
    this.r = r;
    this.angle = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.w, this.h);
  }

  // Should be moved outside of this class.
  update() {
    this.angle += 0.1;
    this.posX = this.cx + this.r * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.posY = this.cy + this.r * Math.sin(this.angle);
    ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.w, this.h)
  }
}

const animate = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  objArr.forEach(e => {
    e.update();
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `[0]` is not correct but not really a problem because OP calls `animate()` after the loop which triggers an `.update()` for every rectangle.